# Is it possible to invoke on a remote computer via a web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, pinvoke

My situation is this..

I have code I use that interfaces with an MMO -- a DLL written in C# -- and I was hoping to hide some of it by putting it in a web service and calling it. I don't want my C# DLL to merely be reversed and expose my method of doing what I'm doing.

For example..

Say I want to PostMessage a key press to the MMO window, but I don't want to actually put that code inside the DLL local to the user's machine. I wanted to call the PostMessage via the web service. Make sense?

As far as I've read, it's not possible. Are there alternatives, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Your example is a good example of why this can't work. `PostMessage` would then run on the server and have absolutely no effect on the client machine.

Comment: I appreciate the expeditious response, and that's what I figured though I wasn't sure that's how that worked. Do you have any ideas as to alternatives? I suppose I could just write a companion C++ DLL and call that.

Comment: One problem with the what you're trying to do here is that there is very little you can do on the client's machine that *can't* be reverse engineered. There is no perfect solution. One approach the company I used to work for took (which is ugly) was to have their apps download dynamic snippets of code from their server (authenticated and encrypted of course) and dynamically compile those portions of the application and only ever invoke them through Reflection. It was their approach to license management and it was good enough but ugly as can be.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I'll just write a companion C++ DLL to make it just a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Some products can prevent reflection on .net dlls, it could solve your problem.

http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/protector.html